# different password using the same hash function sha1

Tags: php

this is for a signup page

```
        $query = $db->prepare ('INSERT INTO user(user_first_name, user_last_name,user_password) VALUES (:f_name, :l_name, :u_pass)');
        $query -> bindParam(':f_name', $_POST['user_fname']);
        $query -> bindParam(':l_name', $_POST['user_lname']);
        $passSh1 = sha1($_POST['user_pass']);
        $query -> bindParam(':u_pass', $passSh1);
```

and this for sign in page

```
            $query1 -> bindParam(':f_name', $_POST['user_fname']);
            $passSh2 = sha1($_POST['user_pass']);
            $query1 -> bindParam(':u_pass', $passSh2);
            echo $passSh2 . '</br';
```

when i try with the password 'z' using the sign up page i get this '395df8f7c51f0070'

and when i try with the sign in page i get '395df8f7c51f007019cb30201c49e884b46b92fa '

Comment: Where are you reading these values? The second hash is correct. The first looks like it's been truncated by something.

Comment: Why this question was tagged with pdo while it's actually asking about hashes? Can't you just compare 2 hashes, without any extra code?

Comment: Don't use `sha1()` to hash your passwords, use bcrypt or the recently added password hashing api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the length allowed for your user_password field in your database, it definitely looks like it is truncating it, and the only way I see that as possible is that you are using `VARCHAR(16)` or something.

Answer (score 0):

sha1 is a 40 character long hash. You should use CHAR(40) .